# Integration x86 x64 Windows 8 RTM

Tags: x86, windows-8

how to integrate the windows 8 x86 and x64 RTM iso
so that it contains all the editions
eg
Windows 8 x64 Enterprise
Windows 8 x86 Enterprise
Windows 8 x64 Professional
Windows 8 x86 Professional

Answer (score 1):

**What You’ll need**

- Installation ISOs for Windows 8 x86 and x64 (any edition)
- ISO creation / editing software such as [UltraISO](http://ultraiso.en.softonic.com/)
- [Windows 7 Automated Installation Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5753) (Since Windows 8 Automated Installation Kit is not out yet, you need to try if the `Windows 7 AIK` can do it for you and hence try making this on a `Windows 7` PC)

If it does NOT work you will have wait for the `Windows 8 Automated Installation Kit` to be released by Microsoft.

**How to Create the Intergated ISO:**

- Using UltraISO, extract the `\SOURCES\INSTALL.WIM` files from both the x86 and x64 ISO files. (If you do not have ISO files you can create them from your DVDs)
- Rename these INSTALL.WIM files as x86.WIM and x64.WIM
- With the Windows 7 AIK installed on your computer run the Deployment Tools Command Prompt
- Type the following commands in the Command Prompt window adding any folder destinations as necessary:
  `IMAGEX /EXPORT x86.WIM 1 INSTALL.WIM “Windows 8 Enterprise x86″`
  `IMAGEX /EXPORT x64.WIM 1 INSTALL.WIM “Windows 8 Enterprise x64″`
- This will integrate all the contents from the various version WIM files into a single INSTALL.WIM file.
- Using UltraISO, copy this new INSTALL.WIM into the SOURCES folder in your Windows 8 x86 ISO file.
- From the SOURCES folder delete the file EI.CFG from the same ISO file. Here is the [Microsoft Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824952.aspx) on these files. If they do **NOT** exist, then skip this step.
- Save the ISO file

**NOTE:**
This method definitely works for Windows 7 & may NOT work for Windows 8 as the Windows 8 AIK is still not out. If this works, this would just be a hack or a work around. I do not see x86 and x64 Slipstreamed DVDs on my TechNet or Bizspark account also.

So I repeat, it may NOT work for Windows 8 and you might have to wait till Windows 8 AIK is out.